# How to redirect to another router when vist "/"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router v4

Below is my code

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div> { /* your usual react-router v4 routing */ }
            <Switch>
                <Route  path="/register"  component={Register} />
                <Route  path="/login"  component={Login} />
                <Route  path="/main"  component={App} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

How can I set /register router is default route or when user visit "/" it will redirect to /register?

Comment: I remember that React router has a featuer called `IndexRoute`, does it solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to conditionally use [`<Redirect />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) straight from the react-router documentation.

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'

<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
  loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
  ) : (
    <PublicHomePage/>
  )
)}/>
```

You should be able to use this example to accomplish what you need. If you need help molding it to your use, let me know!